# What does the term "gold label" refer to in the context of semi-supervised classification?

Tags: classification, semi-supervised-learning

Throughout the Snorkel tutorial here https://github.com/HazyResearch/snorkel and in the team's related white paper there's references to "gold labels", but the term evades definition.

What are 'gold labels' in the semi-supervised classification context?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From https://hazyresearch.github.io/snorkel/blog/snark.html:

> We call this type of training data weak supervision because it’s noisier and less accurate than the expensive, manually-curated “gold” labels that machine learning models are usually trained on. However, Snorkel automatically de-noises this noisy training data, so that we can then use it to train state-of-the-art models.

As I understand it, the goal of Snorkel is to generate a large set of synthetic training data for large-scale ML algorithms by learning from a much smaller set of hand-labeled training data. The hand-labeled training data have been handled by subject-matter experts and thus we are much more certain of the correctness of the label (but obtaining a large set of such data may be prohibitively expensive, hence the impetus for Snorkel in the first place). So it appears they are calling these hand-labeled data "gold" labels, as they represent some reliable ground-truth value. This can be contrasted with the labels output by the algorithm, which are hopefully of high quality but are still subject to noise by construction.

Comment: Thank you, I was needing a source to confirm it and you've provided. Do you know if this is also an industry-wide term?

Comment: @raldy Oftentimes the phrase "gold standard" is used to refer to a measurement system whose outputs are known to be accurate and trustable. So I assume the terminology they use here is a slight offshoot of that, but i can't be 100% sure. If you think my post adequately answered your question, please consider marking this as the "accepted" answer by clicking the little checkmark to the left side of the post.

Comment: Done. If you are interested in feedback, your provided overview of Snorkel and comparison of the value of different sources of supervision was beyond the scope of the question and information I already had.

Comment: A user informs us that the link is broken.  Google searches of the snorkel.ai site do not turn up this exact quotation.  That doesn't really matter, because the quotation stands by itself: this is just an alert to those who might want to read more.